# py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my initial code

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
#
import json

from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameNaFunctions, Row, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, when, arrays_zip, concat_ws, expr, coalesce, to_json, from_json, get_json_object, regexp_replace, schema_of_json, encode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, MapType, StructType, BooleanType
import psycopg2

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local') \
    .appName("PostgresToRedshiftCDCMigration") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/C:/Users/pathikd/Downloads/postgresql-42.5.4.jar,/C:/Users/pathikd/Downloads/redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.16.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql('''SELECT * FROM range(10) where id > 7''').show()
```

This spark.sql is throwing this error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o32.sql. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Why it is throwing this error that sql method does not exist and how to resolve this?
I will be using the spark.sql for complex queries but I am getting this error.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: It's working fine for me - spark version 3.3.1

Comment: Something is wrong with this line `.config("spark.jars", "/C:/Users...`, even the path look wrong

Comment: After moving to spark version 3.3.2 from 3.3.4 it started working.